# Materialize $(...).sideNav is not a function using Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, gulp, materialize

I'm currently having an issue with Materialize and Webpack. I'm trying to create two files index-bundle.js and vendor-bundle.js to contain the different javascript files that my project uses. But I keep running into the issue and getting this error `TypeError: $(...).sideNav is not a function`, I've been trying to figure this one out for a few days now with no luck. If I were to guess it might have something to do with JQuery but I'm unsure. If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

Update:
The error changed to `TypeError: menu.velocity is not a function` after compiling it a few times. Still leads me to believe it has to do with jQuery.

Below are some files that might have some importance.

base.html: https://github.com/MattsLab/MattsLab/blob/master/views/layouts/base.html

webpack.config.js: https://github.com/MattsLab/MattsLab/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Gulp Task:

```
    gulp.task("scripts:build", () => {
    return gulp.src('assets/scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const util = require("gulp-util");
const webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
    production: process.env.NODE_ENV == "production",
};


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: './assets/scripts/app.js',
        vendor: ['jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js'],
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name]-bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/')
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            loader: "babel-loader",
            include: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/scripts"),
            ],
            test: /\.js$/,

            query: {
                presets: ['es2015'],
                plugins: ['transform-runtime']
            }
        }, ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': config.production ? JSON.stringify('production') : process.env.NODE_ENV
            }
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            Hammer: "hammerjs/hammer"
        }),
    ]
};

if (config.production) {
    webpackConfig.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: false
    }))
}
```

app.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav({
        menuWidth: 150
    });
})
```

Comment: Are you working locally or is there a url I can take a look at? The issue is probably related to how the script files are being loaded.

Comment: ^What he said. Make sure Jquery is loaded  before Materialize

Comment: I updated my post to include links to my base.html which is where I'm adding the JS and the webpack config. My whole project is public so everything should be there.

Comment: @MattBrowning: I'm facing same problem, did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit search I was able to solve this issue using following configuration.

**Step 1:**

import Materialize like this:

`import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js'`

**Step 2:**

As mentioned in the original resource:

> MaterializeCSS is not compatible with jQuery 3

Now, clearly not the best solution but it works. Add reference to older version of jQuery in your `html` page:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

**Step 3:**

Add this in your `webpack.config` file:

```
externals: {
  jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

**Finally:**

Initialize plugin:

```
$('.selector').sideNav();
```

**[Original source of answer](https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize/issues/20)**

Answer (score 1):

this works for me replace cdn

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

i had a similar error but and a simple solution worked for me, 
replace the

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

with `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`